# How to use httpMethod = POST on Swift 3 , URLRequest?

Tags: ios, json, swift, httprequest

I have working `json` fetching  codes with `GET` methods but when i convert it to `POST` with adding;

```
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

gives me ;

> Cannot assign to property: 'httpMethod' is a get-only property Error

My codes under below how can fix it ? How can i convert it to `POST`

```
 @discardableResult
    open func  getLoginMethod(_ method: String, parameters: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ login: [Login]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask! {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        guard let url = NSURL(string: parameters) else {
            completionHandler(nil, myErrors.InvalidUrlError)
            return nil
        }
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                completionHandler(nil, myErrors.getError)
            } else {
                do {
                    let login = try self.getLogin(jsonData: data! as NSData)
                    completionHandler(login, nil)
                } catch {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        return task
    }
```

Also my calling codes under below for `get` method my variables inside `parameters` , for `POST` method which changes i need to do ?

```
  AWLoader.show(blurStyle: .dark, shape: .Circle)

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            myApp.sharedInstance().getLoginMethod("", parameters: "http://bla.com/Post?Phone=\(self.phone.text)") {login, error in
                if error != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //  self.showAlert()

                        print(error!)

                        AWLoader.hide()
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.getlogin = login!
                        //    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        //       AWLoader.hide()

                        //  self.loginButton.alpha = 0
                        print(self.getlogin)


                        AWLoader.hide()
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

Thanks

Comment: `NSURLRequest` is not mutable, `NSMutableURLRequest` is. Why don't you use `URLRequest` (more Swift-like)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `NSMutableURLRequest` to be able to modify `httpMethod`. Using `NSURLRequest` won't do.

Example:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

But even better, you should be using `URLRequest` struct:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Your refactored code with additional improvements:

```
@discardableResult
open func getLoginMethod(_ method: String, parameters: String,
                     session: URLSession = .shared,
                     completionHandler: @escaping (_ login: [Login]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask! {

    guard let url = URL(string: parameters) else {
        completionHandler(nil, myErrors.InvalidUrlError)
        return nil
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = method
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
        guard let responseData = data else {
            completionHandler(nil, myErrors.getError)
            return
        }
        do {
            let login = try self.getLogin(jsonData: data as NSData)
            completionHandler(login, nil)
        } catch {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return task
}
```

EDIT:
To answer your second part of the question. It depends on what kind of data format your API is expecting - whether it should be `multipart/form-data` or `json` format, it all depends.
But in general, assuming that you are using `URLRequest` struct that I've mentioned, you should just convert it to `Data` using your serializer and use it like this:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = <your parameters converted to Data>
```

Usually, your API will expect proper `Content-Type` header added to your `URLRequest`:

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: ty but how can i send varibles ? normally i sent them inside parameters: "http://bla.comPostMember?Mobile=\(self.phone.text)" like this but on post how can i send them ?

Comment: i updated my question i added calling method codes on post? how can i send variables ? which ones i need to change ?

Comment: That depends on how you need to send them - what type of encoding, etc, but basically you add them to `request.httpBody`

Comment: please. can you integrate it to my codes i will approve your answer with test.

Comment: Sorry, it's completely another question - if you decide to encode it as JSON it's gonna be completely different than for Multipart/Form-Data - I will describe what you need to set to `URLRequest`, but your question is too general and too broad to answer within this thread. Please accept this answer and add another question like 'how to serialize request parameters for POST request`

Comment: ty but your answer dont work in my codes u answered only first part in my question.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper you simply added new, much more demanding and broad question into your initial. SO is not a tool to teach you what data serialization is all about and write your code for you, but to help you understand some programming concepts or real-code related issues if you have them. I've expanded my answer to help you solve the issue of adding parameters to `POST` request and explained a reasoning. You just need to read a bit about request's parameters serialization. Just be fair.

Comment: ty u updated your answer, i accepted your question now im trying.